# Output/Log Console.Read & Console.Write from a Console application to a TXT/XML File C#

Tags: c#, xml, console

I have a Console application (C#) that interacts with the User, and every step is shown via Console.Writeline.

Now I wanted to write these events to XML or TXT, and my only guess was to create a List and add all the Console.Writelines to it, but then I noticed that logging the Console.Readline is mandatory, and that's the reason I'm asking this question.

How do I log Console.Reads/Console.Writes to a TXT/XML?

Thank you.

Comment: You want to know how to write to a text file????

Comment: Every journey has a beginning...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to accomplish this is to use [File.AppendAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356)

> Opens a file, appends the specified string to the file, and then closes the file. If the file does not exist, this method creates a file, writes the specified string to the file, then closes the file.

Something like this

```
string line = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine(line); // I gather you want to write it out again?
File.AppendAllText(@"C:\SomePath\MyFile.txt", line);
```

If you would prefer to gather all of the text first and then write it all out when your program exits, you could do something like this:

```
List<string> inputLines = new List<string>();

// Loop here getting lines
string line = Console.ReadLine();
inputLines.Add(line);

// When done:
File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\SomePath\MyFile.txt", inputLines.ToArray());
```

See

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92e05ft3

Comment: It would append the next line to the end of the file, or create it first if it does not.  Check out the link I provided.

Comment: No I mean if the MyFile.txt file doesn't already exist at that path it won't create it. Maybe he should use FileStream with OpenOrCreate and then StreamWriter to write.

Comment: Ok I get it. Never used that method before.

Comment: What confuses me is, this process is similar to gathering a string as an item and keep them added to a List<string>. So is this the way to go? Everytime I used console.readline, I have to append it everytime? Suppose this is the only way, I would like to make this easier by getting all the text from console.writeline, how would i do that? Simply saying, how would I copy the text that shows in the ConsoleWindow?

Comment: I added another alternative that gathers the input in a list and writes it all out when the program is about to exit.

Comment: Excellent now! Though I'm sorry I'm a beginner so I'm going to pose my last question. IN:
File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\SomePath\MyFile.txt", inputLines.ToArray());

The "Path", I wanted to know how can I write the output to where the Executable Runs? Like those XML Outputs. I want it to write it to the same directory the Executable runs from. Something dynamic I mean.

Comment: Okay I got it. simply writing a filename without any path before it does the trick. But I'm not sure why the output doesn't write the Console.WriteLines, I mean the text from the Console. It only write the Readlines - inputLines.ToArray().

Thank you

Comment: I think there has been a misunderstanding LOL, I actually wanted to output everything that shows on the Console. I searched a lot and the Console.Setout does the trick but the problem is that with that on, the text does not appear to the console, but everything goes in the background and is written to a file. Then i searched for Mirroring, and I believe the only way to solve this would be to separately add each and every console.writeline/readline to the List of strings, and then write it out.
So yea, thanks again becaues I'll be using the same lines you provided. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use [log4net](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14819/How-to-use-log4net) which is a free logging tool for .net

Comment: Good idea but it's always more fun to build it yourself. And in this case it's not too much work and a great learning experience.